#  partial template specialization in MSVC++2010 with defaults

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization, visual-c++-2010

The following snippet won't compile on MSVC++2010 (compiles fine with gcc, icc and sun CC):

```
#include <iostream>

template< class T, unsigned D > struct Attribute
{
    T attr[D];
};

template< class T, unsigned D, class A = Attribute< T, D > > struct Point
{
    T coor[D];
    A a;
};

template< class P1, class P2 > struct Pair;

template< class T1, class T2, unsigned D > struct Pair< Point< T1, D>, Point< T2, D > >
{
    Point< T1, D> p1;
    Point< T2, D> p2;

    static const char * id()
    {
        return "specialized";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Pair< Point< float, 3>, Point< double, 3> > p;

    std::cout << p.id() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I remove a default for `class A` from `Point` declaration it compiles just fine. Any suggestions on how to work around this issue without changing non-specialized declaration of Pair (i.e., `template< class P1, class P2 > struct Pair;`) are greatly appreciated. Removing defaults in the real code is not an option either.

```
error C2079: 'p' uses undefined struct 'Pair<P1,P2>'
          with
          [
              P1=Point<float,3>,
              P2=Point<double,3>
          ]
```

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?

Comment: Are you passing the 3rd (default) argument to `struct Point` ever ? I mean is `class A` is always a default parameter `Attribute<T,D>` ?

Comment: Yes, I do, most of the time it is the default but in some cases it is completely different type. Btw this snippet is for demonstration only. The real code is much more complex and much more convoluted.

Comment: Have you tried using 3U rather than 3?

Comment: I just tried, same error. Whatever the reason VC++ compiler does not match the specialized template and wants to instantiate the non-specialized one.

Answer (score 2):

Point's 3rd template parameter should appear in the specialization:

```
template<class T1, class T2, unsigned D>
struct Pair<Point<T1, D, Attribute<T1, D>>, Point<T2, D, Attribute<T2, D>>>
{ ... };
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a step in the right direction but won't work (on VC++) if T1/T2 are themselves templated classed with defaults.

Comment: Then ask another question with those defaults.

Comment: It is not know what T1 and T2 are beforehand.

Comment: Of course it's not known what T1 and T2 are, that's why the're template parameters of the specialization.  I don't see how that's relevant to the current question.